# Ruby: Shorthand for a[1] || a[3] || a[6] ...?

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar

I have a regular expression that returns multiple variables within a match. I am interested in the first non-null variable in a subset of indices within the match, so I am using

```
result = a[1] || a[3] || a[6] || ...
```

I would like to store the relevant indices in a configuration file along with the regular expression itself. What is the best shorthand notation that doesn't obfuscate the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `values_at` to get an array which contains only the elements at the specified indices. Then use `find {|x| x}` to get the first element that is not nil or false.

```
result = a.values_at(*indices).find {|x| x}
```

Comment: The question said non-null, so assuming that means the bad values are `nil`, this could be simplified to `a.values_at(*indices).compact.first`.

Comment: Does `compact` guarantee order persistence?

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
result = [1,3,6].find {|x| a[x]}
```

Comment: It is actually supposed to be `a[ [1,3,6].find {|x| a|x|} ]` which is a little less aesthetic.